# Flutter Stream<ProductCategory> to List<TreeViewNode>

Tags: flutter, dart, treeview

I have TreeView data. I keep this data in Firebase. I get this data from Firebase with the ProductCategory model.

There is a List field in the ProductCategory model. I keep the link of children's areas with this area.

I need to convert the **Stream<List<**ProductCategory**>>** data to **Stream<List<**TreeViewNode**>>**.

```
class ProductCategory {
  final String key;
  final String label;
  final Stream <List <ProductCategory>> children;
 }

class TreeViewNode {
 final String key;
 final Streing label;
 final List <TreeViewNode> children;
}
```

I need your help

Comment: Provide codes please.

Comment: please can you add whats the structure of `ProductCategory`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.transform()` with `StreamTransformer` to transform stream to another, example:

```
Stream<List<TreeViewNode>> get myPostsStream =>
      stream.transform(
        StreamTransformer<ProductCategory, List<TreeViewNode>>.fromHandlers(
            handleData:
                (ProductCategory value, EventSink<List<TreeViewNode>> sink) {
          sink.add(value.actions);
        }),
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your interest.

I wonder if you can help a little more. Below I give a snippet of code in the repository. Using this code, you can find the function I want to write.

```
Stream<List<ProductCategory>> getChildProductCategories(
      String id, DocumentReference parentRef) {
    Stream<List<ProductCategory>> result = _firebaseRepository
        .getStreamDocumentList(_productChildCategoryRef(id, parentRef.parent))
        .map(
          (snapshot) => snapshot.docs
              .map((doc) => ProductCategory.fromJson(
                    doc.id,
                    doc.data(),
                    ref: doc.reference,
                    childProductCategories:
                        getChildProductCategories(doc.id, doc.reference),
                    parentRef: parentRef,
                  ))
              .toList(),
        );
    return result;
  }

  Stream<List<ProductCategory>> getStreamCategoryList() {
    try {
      Stream<List<ProductCategory>> result =
          _firebaseRepository.getStreamDocumentList(_productCategoryRef).map(
                (snapshot) => snapshot.docs
                    .map(
                      (doc) => ProductCategory.fromJson(
                        doc.id,
                        doc.data(),
                        ref: doc.reference,
                        childProductCategories:
                            getChildProductCategories(doc.id, doc.reference),
                      ),
                    )
                    .toList(),
              );
      return result;
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      throw ProductCategoryFailure(e.code);
    }
  }

Stream<List<TreeViewNode>> getStreamTreeViewNodeList(Stream<List<ProductCategory>> streamProductCategoryList){
  ??????
}
```